# Convert timestamps into fraction of day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the time in the format hh:mm into the fraction of the day . I have the dataframe in which I have the column of duration

```
Duration
0:56
0:54
2:57
```

**I want to convert this column into the fraction of day**

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with fraction of day? So the convert the duration to the fraction of 24 hours?

Comment: yes fraction of hh:mm into the fraction of 24 hours

Comment: Post expected output to the question. What's the fraction of the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. We can split the duration in hours and minutes, then convert the minutes to fraction of hours and finally check the fraction of the day by summing both:

```
split = df['Duration'].str.split(':')
h = split.str[0].astype(int)
m = split.str[1].astype(int)
df['fraction_24_hrs'] = (h + m / 60) / 24
```

```
  Duration  fraction_24_hrs
0     0:56         0.038889
1     0:54         0.037500
2     2:57         0.122917
```

---

**Option 2**, would be to use the pandas timedelta functionality:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration'], format='%H:%M')
df['fraction_24_hrs'] = (dates - dates.dt.floor('D')) / pd.Timedelta(24, 'H')
```

```
  Duration  fraction_24_hrs
0     0:56         0.038889
1     0:54         0.037500
2     2:57         0.122917
```